# save content of include in variable

Tags: twig

I have a twig template that uses `batch()` to make some columns like that:

```
{% set rows = collection|batch(3) %}
```

As documented here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/batch.html this function takes a second argument to define the string that is used for "missing" elements.

I am looking for something like that:

```
{% set html = include 'path/to/file.html.twig' %} <-- parse error
{% set rows = collection|batch(3, html) %}
```

Is there a way to do that or something else I can/should do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can assign a chunk of text by using the following snippet:

<kbd>main.twig</kbd>

```
{% set foo %}
    {% include 'foo.twig' %}
{% endset %}

{% set items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'] %}

<table>
{% for row in items|batch(3, foo) %}
    <tr>
        {% for column in row %}
            <td>{{ column }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

<kbd>foo.twig</kbd>

```
<div>
    <h1>Foo</h1>
</div>
```

[twigfiddle](http://twigfiddle.com/u6u4m0)

Comment: Thanks! Gonna look at it in a rush ;)